# String formatting : Replace "%0 %1 %2" with tuple with 0,1,2 indexes

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I am a beginner in python. I found a question in python that Given string in format "%0 is a %1 %2" and a tuple ("Ram", "good", "boy"). Means string contains %x where it should be replaced with the respective tuple element of index x. (after edit ): Forgot to mention, If given tuple is ("Ram", "good")., answer must be "Ram is a good %2" i.e, remaining %x should be left as it is

The result must be "Ram is a good boy". I did it like this(below is the code). But I came to know that it could be written in more efficient way , in less no. of lines...Could u pls help how ? Thanks in advance

```
format = "%0 is a %1 %2"
args = ("Ram", "good", "boy")
count = 0
for i in range(0, len(format) + 1):
    if format[i] == '%':
        b= '%'
        b = b + format[i + 1]

        format = format.replace(b, args[int(format[i+1])])
        count+= 1

        if count == len(args):
            break

print format
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `str.format`, you can simply unpack the tuple:

```
args = ("Ram", "good", "boy")


print("{}  is a {} {}".format(*args))
Ram is  a good boy
```

If you need to manipulate the original string first use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) :

```
import re

"%2 and %1 and %0"
 args = ("one", "two", "three")

print(re.sub(r"%\d+", lambda x: "{"+x.group()[1:]+"}", s).format(*args))
```

Output:

```
In [6]: s = "%2 and %1 and %0"

In [7]: re.sub(r"%\d+", lambda x: "{"+x.group()[1:]+"}", s).format(*args)
Out[7]: 'three and two and one'

In [8]: s = "%1 and %0 and %2"

In [9]: re.sub(r"%\d+",lambda x: "{"+x.group()[1:]+"}", s).format(*args)
Out[9]: 'two and one and three'
```

`%\d+` matches a percent sign followed by 1 or more digits,  the `x` in the lambda is a match object which we use `.group` to get the matched string from and slice just the digits wrapping the number string in `{}` to use as placeholders for `str.format`.

Re comment that you can have more placeholders than args, sub takes a `count` arg of the max amount of replacements to make:

```
s = "%0 is a %1 %2"
args = ("Ram", "Good")
sub = re.sub(r"%\d+\b", lambda x: "{"+x.group()[1:]+"}", s,count=len(args)).format(*args)

print(sub)
```

Output:

```
Ram is a Good %2
```

To work for arbitrary order, it is going to take more logic:

```
s = "%2 is a %1 %0"
args = ("Ram", "Good")

sub = re.sub(r"%\d+\b", lambda x: "{"+x.group()[1:]+"}" if int(x.group()[1:]) < len(args) else x.group(), s).format(*args)

print(sub)
```

Output:

```
%2 is a Good Ram
```

Moving the lambda logic to a function is a little nicer:

```
s = "%2 is a %1 %0"
args = ("Ram", "Good")
def f(x):
    g = x.group()
    return "{"+g[1:]+"}" if int(x.group()[1:]) < len(args) else g

sub = re.sub(r"%\d+\b",f,  s).format(*args)
```

Or using split and join if the placeholders are always on their own:

```
print(" ".join(["{"+w[1:]+"}" if w[0] == "%" else w for w in s.split(" ")]).format(*args))

three and two and one
```

Comment: what if the input string = "%2  and %1 and %0" and args = ("one", "two", "three"), the answer must be "three and two and one"....

Comment: @ManojCh, the second part of the answer takes care of that

Comment: I think he means what if the order of the tokens are not the same as the order of the items in the tuple. like it should output `'three and two and one'` in that case

Comment: @RNar then  reverse the args

Comment: @ManojCh, if you have different possible scenarios you should add then to your question.

Comment: in your answer, string contains {}.. but the given input string contains %x., where int(x) is the index of tuple element to be replaced with

Comment: @ManojCh, add that to your question

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham thank you ! I am expecting a single line answer u said...print(re.sub(r"%(\d+)",lambda x: "{"+x.group()[1:]+"}", s).format(*args)) But got an error and error details are here : **NameError: name 're' is not defined**

Comment: @ManojCh you have to `import re`

Comment: Heyy! it worked., thank you @ Padraic Cunningham...I have no idea of re.sub can you refer me some links to know about that ...and one more question is that do we have any alternatives to get output ?

Comment: @ManojCh, what do you mean by alternatives?

Comment: another solutions without importing anything ! in python , there will be lot many approaches to get the answer . right ?

Comment: @ManojCh, it depends, if the placeholders are always like you have in your examples, the list comp and splitting will work, it really depends on how complicated the string is

Comment: Heyy ! Once check out the question ! done some edits

Comment: @ManojCh, I don't see anything different, the code above will work for any input

Comment: I'm getting indexerror, tupple out of range if s = "%0 %1 %2" and args = ("Ram", "Good")

Comment: @ManojCh, of course you are, you have three placeholders and you pass two args. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: i have three testcases that have to pass.. first two have passed but., third test case details: string = "%0 is a %1 %2" , args = ("Ram", "Good"), for this we getting index error, but the expected output is "Ram is a good %2"

Comment: @ManojCh, the edit will work with what you have in your comment, if the order can be 2,1,0 etc.. the it won't

Answer (score 0):

use the built in string formatting.

```
>>> print('%s is a %s %s' % ('Ram','good','boy'))
Ram is a good boy
```

According to your edit, you are looking for something different. You can use `re.findall` and `re.sub` to accomplish this:

```
>>> import re
>>> formatstring,args = "%0 is a %1 %2",("Ram", "good", "boy")    
>>> for x in re.findall('(%\d+)',formatstring):
    formatstring = re.sub(x,args[int(x[1:])],formatstring)

>>> formatstring
'Ram is a good boy'
```

Comment: if the given string contains %s , its cool we can use it ! But the string is "%0  is %1 %2". If i do print('%0  is %1 %2' % args), it wont work ryt !

Comment: correct. why do you have it in this format? it can be changed with some `re.sub` magic but seems like an XY problem to me.

Comment: @RNar: he is doing an exercise of some sort that requires him to use a string with %0, %1 etc formatting.

Comment: `re.sub` can do it all with a lambda

Comment: @PadraicCunningham never knew `re.sub` can take a callable, that's amazing. won't edit for fear of being a dup answer but yours is definitely a cleaner answer

Comment: @RNar, yep, x is basically a match object

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `string.replace` to replace the various `%x`es with their tuple counterparts, like:

```
format = "%0 is a %1 %2"
args = ("Ram", "good", "boy")

result = format  # Set it here in case args is the empty tuple

for index, arg in enumerate(args):
    formatter = '%' + str(index)  # "%0", "%1", etc
    result = result.replace(formatter, arg)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you sir ! can we do it using lambda ? i mean in any other way without using a loop ?

Comment: Well, Padraic Cunningham's answer uses a regex instead of a loop. I'm not really interested in trying to introduce lambdas here (and I don't see an obvious way how), I feel they only make the code worse.